# What does "be out" here mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "be out" mean in this excerpt:

> So just to recap real quick, make sure your car’s back into drive, signal to the left so that you're indicating which way you're pulling out, you're going to check your left side mirror to make sure you have enough room, and then right before you actually pull out, you must turn your head. Turn over your left shoulder, make sure there’s enough room to safely pull out and when all of that happens, pull out of that spot and you’ll **be out there** and driving safely again.

Source: [this driving video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHLd6WIQNgQ)

Comment: The contraction for "you are" is *you're*. You will be out there (that is, on the road).

Comment: Parking spot would be meant if it said "out *of* there".

Comment: And we normally say "Look over your left shoulder" rather than "Turn over your left shoulder."

Comment: Please, [tell us where you find your source](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084) In this case, knowing this is someone's speech, not the written word, helps us understand why it's worded the way that it is.

Comment: Yeah, that "turn over your shoulder" is not right. "turn [your head to the left and look] over your shoulder" is what he meant. But the preceding sentence already said **turn** your head, so this sentence only needs to say **look** over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than grouping "be out" together, it is probably easier to understand if you read it like "[You will be] [out there] [driving safely again]".

By "out there", he means, "on the road". "Out there" could refer to any location, though. You could say, "Get out there and have an adventure!" if you were telling someone to get out of the house and go do something.

As a side note, whoever wrote this driving guide was speaking very informally. There are a lot of grammar mistakes. It's good to practice reading this kind of writing, but don't worry too much if something doesn't make sense.

As another side note, if you say that a person "is out" about something, it means they had a secret, but now everyone knows about it. Therefore, to "be out" means that people know about your secret. You hear this phrase most often when someone who is a homosexual tells people about it for the first time. When I read the title of your post, I thought it would be that kind of question, haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply an informal way of saying you will be out on the road.